# Gradle sync failed in opening a Kotlin project on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem with opening my Kotlin project on Android Studio. What should I do to solve the problem? The error log I'm receiving is:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle` and then uncheck the `Offline work` option. Hit Apply & Ok. Sync the `gradle.build` file again.

Go to `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart` and select `Invalidate and Restart` from the dialog box if the error persists.

If still there's any problem syncing the library files, check if the following `maven` section is there as it is below in your project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven {
             url "https://maven.google.com"
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are all the libraries are added in the `build.gradle` file properly and synced with the Internet turned on?

Comment: How can I check it?